# Is it any useful to have a `public static final String MODULE = SomeClass.class.getName();` in a java class

Tags: java

I am seeing a lot of lines like `public static final String MODULE = SomeClass.class.getName();` in my company's internal code base. I am very curious why such a line is any useful, because I can't find any usage of the constant `MODULE`. So, why are they there? What are the use cases?

Comment: i could think of having to compare class names but not printing everytime all this thing `SomeClass.class.getName();`. i guess for smaller code. cant think of sth else

Comment: No. If you can access `MODULE` you can access the containing class, and you therefore already know its name.

Comment: I think it might also be some baggage brought over by some other developers which used other programming languages such as C/C++, meaning that it was more of a habit and served no particular value...

Comment: Are there usages of the `MODULE` field via reflection, perhaps in logging or some other cross cutting code? Try looking for `"MODULE"` (including the quotes) in your code base, a library your code uses or your container's code.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static final String MODULE = SomeClass.class.getName();
```

This type of code generally used for maintaining the log files using this they are getting the module name using which they can track down the flow of execution, in short it helps for debugging...!

Comment: It helps for debugging how?

Comment: Debugging means you can view log file which prints module name with exception or any error..! using module name you can get your bug